# Show Pagination Numbers beyond Current Page. 

Tags: php

UPDATE: I have revised my code and I now can display current page but it shows 0 for first page. and when they move onto more pages it shows current page and previous pages. How do I get it to show a set number of pages.

```
<div id="paging">       
<div class="page">
    <?php if ($pageNum_getDisplay > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
                <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getDisplay=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_getDisplay); ?>">First</a>
                <?php } // Show if not first page ?></div>
<div class="page">
    <?php if ($pageNum_getDisplay > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
                <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getDisplay=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_getDisplay - 1), $queryString_getDisplay); ?>">Previous</a>
                <?php } // Show if not first page ?></div>
<div class="page">
    <?php for ($i=0;$i<=$pageNum_getDisplay;$i++){     
    if ($pageNum_getDisplay==$i)         
    echo ($i);     
    else         
    echo "<a title='Page $i' href='?pageNum_getDisplay=$i'><strong>$i</strong></a>"; 
    } ?> </div>
<div class="page"> 
    <?php if ($pageNum_getDisplay < $totalPages_getDisplay) { // Show if not last page ?>
                <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getDisplay=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_getDisplay, $pageNum_getDisplay + 1), $queryString_getDisplay); ?>">Next</a></div>             
<div class="page">
    <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
            <?php if ($pageNum_getDisplay < $totalPages_getDisplay) { // Show if not last page ?>
                <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getDisplay=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_getDisplay, $queryString_getDisplay); ?>">Last</a>
                <?php } // Show if not last page ?>
        </div>
```

I want to display it so it looks like this.

(first page) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 Next Last 
(second page) First Previous 1 2* 3 4 5 6 7 Next Last

right now it looks like this .. First Previous 0 1 2 Next Last

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to explain a litt;e better what you want to do. I am seeing some code that looks like a pagination bar. What do you want to do with it? What have you tried?

Comment: I know this doesn't help your current situation, but as a general rule of thumb, try to avoid using `<table>`s unless displaying tabular data. Instead use a styled `<div>` which is more flexible and can be more easily modified using CSS.

Comment: Hi, I got this code from Dreamweaver when I first built my site. It works and is functional but I would like to have numbers ( 1, 2, 3, ... Next Last). Dreamweaver doesn't have a number option so I thought there could be some code rewriting someone can figure out without having me rewrite the entire thing.